# Why the color of "with" function is yellow even though it's not a extend function?

Tags: android, kotlin

As I know extend functions' color is yellow on Kotlin. But "with" function actually is a scope function but not a extend function and its color is also yellow. Why the color of "with" function is yellow?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to understand. Kotlin is a programming language, and programming languages have no colours. The colours are only visible in the editor of an IDE, and every IDE, in fact every version and every colour scheme within it, has a different set of colours.

I assume you are talking about Android Studio with the Darcula colour scheme. The colour schemes are explained at the [Jetbrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html).

Looking at the colour scheme for Kotlin, I see what you mean. The "with" function should come under "Package-level functions" in `Settings→Editor→Color Schemes→Kotlin` which defines it as white, but it seems to have the same yellow colour as "Extension functions". This looks like a bug in the IDE, but is not serious enough to matter.